# Find $y'$ for $\ln(x+y)=\arctan(xy)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, implicit-differentiation

> Find $y'$ for $\ln(x+y)=\arctan(xy)$

Here is my attempt at a solution. Is this correct? Any hints or advice would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Looks right. You misapplied the product rule in the third line but magically corrected it in the fourth.

Comment: @rogerl Thanks- I caught my mistake during line four and forgot to correct line three...

Comment: the third line is incorrect, maybe you know it

Comment: A correction on your notation: $\dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$ is an operator, and $\dfrac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ is a variable.

Comment: @GFauxPas thanks, noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the result is correct, I guess that a systematic use of total differentiation makes things slightly easier.

Consider $$F=\log(x+y)-\tan^{-1}(xy)=0$$ So $F'_x~dx+F'_y~dy=0$. I this case, $$F'_x=\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac{y}{x^2 y^2+1}$$ $$F'_y=\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac{x}{x^2 y^2+1}$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=\frac{\frac{y}{x^2 y^2+1}-\frac{1}{x+y}}{\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac{x}{x^2 y^2+1}}=\frac{y \left(x+y-x^2y\right)-1}{x^2 \left(y^2-1\right)-x y+1}=- \frac{(x+y)y-(1+x^2y^2)}{(x+y)x-(1+x^2y^2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

whilst your answer cannot be improved on, it may be of interest to look at a parametric approach. if we set: $\xi $ to be the common value of $\log(x+y)$ and $\arctan(xy)$ then $x$ and $y$ are the two roots of:
$$
z^2 -e^{\xi}z + \tan \xi =0
$$
differentiating with respect to $\xi$ gives:
$$
2zz' - e^{\xi}(z+z') +\sec^2 \xi =0
$$
or
$$
 z' (2z-x-y) = (x+y)z - (1+x^2y^2)
$$
if we substitute the roots $x$ and $y$ for $z$ we obtain:
$$
z_y' (y-x) = (x+y)y-(1+x^2y^2) \\
z_x' (x-y) = (x+y)x-(1+x^2y^2)
$$ 
hence:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{z_y'}{z_x'} = - \frac{(x+y)y-(1+x^2y^2)}{(x+y)x-(1+x^2y^2)}
$$